# Collecting Data from Facebook Group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm not one of the Facebook Developer, but I need some data for my thesis, regarding one group in Facebook which I'm currently observing.

The problem is, I must collect the data within the last 6 months of:

- how many members have joined in the last 6 months, if possible, can be split by monthly.
- how many postings in the group in the last 6 months, also.. if possible split by monthly
- how many active users within the last 6 months.

Can somebody give me some hints of how to collect those information?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a hard time doing this. Groups aren't very API friendly, and they don't have their own insights information.

You can try browsing the group's feed using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) using the `/GROUP_NAME_OR_ID/feed` edge, and adding `since` and `until` filters to look at monthly data.

However, you won't see all the posts because of [Facebook privacy filtering](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/). To get the most reliable data, you'll need to manually count the entries of interest from within the Facebook webapp.

Comment: I really just want to know the members location, nothing else. Isn't it possible to query `/group/members/` and then the location for each member? If I am the group admin of course. thank you for your answer.